# Mobile browsers leaving whitespace with Animate.css

Tags: css, mobile, safari, animate.css

Been using Animate.css to set up some whole-page animations on my site, however, I've found that mobile browsers seem to fail to recalculate the page size after the animation is over, often leaving a massive whitespace where the element began its animation onto the screen.

Basically, I have Animate.css animating entire page sized divs to slide in from the side and from the bottom, while side divs appear to not cause the bug as much, slideUp appears to leave the space at the bottom a lot. All divs are set to `display: none` after the animations finish.

It may be related to having `overflow-y: visible;` on my body.

I'm really seeing the issues on an iPad I'm testing on, Chrome eventually detects the new page size and removes the whitespace(after some delay), and Safari appears to just never figure it out.

Any ideas of hacks that may force mobile browsers to recalculate page size, or a more specific fix?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I think I ended up redoing my animations altogether(I think I ended up using Velocity.js), and removing a lot of the complicated calculations like shadows to speed things up. So I don't think I ever fixed this specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue but I was only animating in from the sides. Adding `overflow-x: hidden;` to the main `div` fixed this for me, so you may want to think about not using `overflow-y: visible`; somehow. It seems to be a bug with mobile browsers.

Comment: it's way too general answer, which doesn't bring any value.

Comment: I think this works for the overflow-x hidden, but I want people to be able to scroll down, so overflow-y needs to be visible.